# intellij idea mark all changes in pull request

Tags: github, intellij-idea, pull-request

Intellij IDEA will mark the code changes that I made but not committed yet like the following (green bar on the left of the new code):
[image]

This is very good to help me spot what code got changed from last commit. I am wondering if there is a similar function (or operation that I can perform) so that when I review a pull request, I can have intellij IDEA mark all the code change in the PR just like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. The following requests seem similar to what you need:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85079
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24398